# "It is clear that most noticeable change that occurred in the town was that of a huge lake."

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

> It is clear that most noticeable change that occurred in the town was **the change of** a huge lake.

> It is clear that most noticeable change that occurred in the town was **that of** a huge lake.

Is the meaning of two sentences above the same?

Comment: What does it mean? That an existing lake changed, or that there was now a lake where there wasn't one before?

Comment: In either case, it should be _the most noticeable change_.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. It is clear that most noticeable change that occurred in the town was the change of a huge lake.
> 2. It is clear that most noticeable change that occurred in the town was that of a huge lake.

As we are referring to a specific change, the definite article should be included.  Also, the phrase *that occurred* seems redundant.

> 1. It is clear that [the] most noticeable change in the town was the change of a huge lake.
> 2. It is clear that [the] most noticeable change in the town was that of a huge lake.

Example 1 suggests more of *the change* of a huge lake; example 2 could have a wider range of meanings, including the presence of a new lake.